# Add props to a component that already has an onClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to React and TypeScript.

I have created a simple component as such:

```
const CloseButton = ({ onClick }: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <CloseIcon className={classes.closeButtonStyles} onClick={onClick} />;
};

export default CloseButton;
```

I'd now like to be able to pass this component styles with `className` as props, so I have added:

```
interface CloseButtonProps {
  className?: string;
}
```

But I am unsure of how to add `className` to the component.

Normally I would do it like

```
const CloseButton = ({ className }: CloseButtonProps) => {
```

But I am unsure of how to do this alongside the `onClick` above.

Would anyone know how best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine your two props into one interface:

```js
interface CloseButtonProps
{
    className?: string
    onClick: MouseEventHandler
}

const CloseButton = ({ className, onClick }: CloseButtonProps) =>
{
    // However you plan on integrating className
}

export default CloseButton
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface CloseButtonProps {
  className?: string;
  onClick?: (e:React.MouseEvent<any>) => void;
  /* You can add another props  here */
}


const CloseButton = ({ className, onClick }: CloseButtonProps) => {
  ...
}
```